Rotating a 2D function in 3D space
Suppose we are given a function $f(x)$ in the x-y plane. We add a z axis perpendicular to this plane and rotate the function 360 degrees about an axis $x=x_0$ (on the x-y plane) in this new 3-dimensional space, getting a new 3D function $f(x, y)$ in the process. To be clear, this 360 degree rotation sweeps out a 3D shape (for instance, if $f(x)$ was a normal distribution, the required $f(x, y)$ would be a "hill" shape). My question is, given $f(x)$ and $x_0$, how do we determine $z = f(x, y)$ in general?

Sorry, it not clear to me what kind of rotation you are looking for. Is $x=x_0$ an axis in the $y-x$ plane? In this case we don't obtain a function by a rotation of 360°.

If we have a function in the $x-y$ plane and rotate it 360 degrees about the line $x = x_0$ we are left with the same function

In general, we obtain a function if we consider $x\ge x_0$ (or $\le x_0$).

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_of_revolution#Coordinate_expressions

@mr_e_man It seems the asker is looking for something different, that is a rotation around the axis $x=x_0$ (parallel to $y$).

$x=x_0$ is not an "axis" in $3$-dimensional space, it is a plane.  It's very unclear what you are trying to do.

@RobertIsrael It seems that the $x=x_0$ axis is the one in the plane $y-x$ that is the axis parallel to $y$.

Notice that "$f(x)$" is a function of one variable that can be graphed in a 2D plane. What do you mean by "$f(x,y,z)$"?

Extremely sorry for the silly errors in describing the question. I have updated the question; there shouldn't be any misunderstanding now.

In general to obtain a function we need restrict the domain of the original function to rotate for $x\ge x_0$ or for $x\le x_0$ otherwise, in general, by a rotation of $360°$ we obtain different value for $z$ with possible intersections (unless $y=f(x)$ is symmetric with respect to $x=x_0$ axis).
For the case of rotation of $y=f(x)$ for the side with $x\ge x_0$ we obtain
$$y(x,z)=f\left(x_0+\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+z^2}\right)$$
and for the case of rotation of $y=f(x)$ for the side with $x\le x_0$ we obtain
$$y(x,z)=f\left(x_0-\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+z^2}\right)$$

For example, for the simple function $y=x^2$ with $x_0=2$ for the side with $x\le 2$ we obtain
$$y(x,z)=\left(2-\sqrt{(x-2)^2+z^2}\right)^2$$


You might need to shift the $x$ coordinate (rotation around $x_0$). +1

@Andrei Oh yes I fix that! My solution is for a rotation around the $x$ axis. Thanks

I have updated my question with the necessary clarifications. So sorry for the careless errors in describing the question at first. I was looking for a function for the form $z = f(x, y)$.

If we start in a $x-y$ plane and rotate the function around the axis $x=x_0$  at the end we obtain something in the form $y=F(x,z)$ that is the form I’ve given. We can redefine the axis of course.
